# Simplify query to just 'where' by making new column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with SQL queries to a column. These are implemented on a function called `Select_analysis`

Form:

```
Select_analysis (input_shapefile, output_name, {where_clause}) # it takes until where.
```

Example:

```
SELECT * from OT         # OT is a dataset
GROUP BY OT.CA  # CA is a number that may exist many times.Therefore we group by that field.
HAVING ((Count(OT.OBJECTID))>1) # an id that appears more than once.
```

OT dataset

```
objectid     CA
1            125
2            342
3            263
1            125
```

We group by CA.

About having: it is applied to the rows that have objectid more than once. Which is the objectid 1 in this example.

My idea is to make another column that will store a result that will be accessed with a simple where clause in the `select_analysis` function

example: OT dataset

```
objectid     CA       count_of_objectid_aftergroupby
1            125           2
2            342           1
3            263           1
1            125           2
```

So then can be:

```
Select_analysis(roads.shp,output.shp, count_of_objectid_aftergroupby > '1')
```

**Notes**

it has to be in such a way so that `select analysis` function is used in the end.

Comment: Is this a pandas problem ?

Comment: Yes,although it contains SQL.The reason is that I have to use a database engine that only supports until the `where` clause. So using pandas I may be able to do the calculations and store them in a way to close the process with just a where query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are pulling the data into pandas since it's tagged pandas, here's one possible solution:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'objectID':[1,2,3,1],'CA':[125,342,463,125]}).set_index('objectID')


objectID    CA
1           125
2           342
3           463
1           125

df['count_of_objectid_aftergroupby']=[df['CA'].value_counts().loc[x] for x in df['CA']]

objectID    CA  count_of_objectid_aftergroupby  
1           125                              2
2           342                              1
3           463                              1
1           125                              2
```

The list comp does basically this:
pull the value counts for each item in df['CA'] as a series.
Use `loc` to index into the series at each value of 'CA' to find the count of that value
Put that item into a list
append that list as a new column

Comment: I think OP is trying to programmatically create SQL queries based on a DataFrame column. The data itself is not in the DataFrame.

Comment: I think you may very well be right, but since it's very unclear what OP is asking and they tagged it with `pandas` and not `sql`, I'll leave it.

Comment: This certainly looks like the example in the question, thanks.In your opinion is this going to turn a having query to just a `where` or you think it may be a better approach?

Comment: @user51332, again it's hard to say because your question is pretty unclear. If you do this bit in pandas, then yes, you can use `WHERE count_of_... >1`, or you can use it in a `HAVING` during a join. I have no opinion because I don;t know your situation, I would personally test the options on small scale and see what works better/faster for your purpose

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain a little th list comprehension you did there i read about loc but explain it if you can.

Comment: Edited answer with explanation